# How to compute values of $Q(\lambda)$ distribution (Kolmogorov test)?

Tags: probability

I am solving examples with Kolmogorov test. It is said that to test hypothesis I need to find critical value of $D_n$ to know if null hypothesis is to be rejected or not. The $Q$ distribution is described as:

$$Q(\lambda)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P \left( \frac{D_n}{\sqrt{n}}<\lambda\right)=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^j e^{-2 j^2 \lambda^2}$$

How to use it to obtain $p$-value or critical value $D_{n, \alpha}$?

Comment: Something is missing in your infinite series. As it is now, I don't have the impression it is convergent.

Comment: In fact it was missing - $j$ was missing in the power of $e$. Now it is the same as in the book.

Comment: Still wrong. Try $j^2$ instead of $j$.

Comment: Then it does converge. However still I have no idea how to find critical $D_n$

Comment: The series represents some [Theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). So you need an inverse of it.